# Scala XML substitution from xml file

Tags: xml, scala, substitution

In Scala, you can easily do XML substitution. For example :

```
val to = "foo"
val from = "bar"
val myXML = <note>
  <to>{to}</to>
  <from>{from}</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Which returns :

```
<note>
  <to>foo</to>
  <from>bar</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I would like to do the same thing from an xml file (my XML is much more complex), I mean loading the xml file this way and perform variable substitution just after :

```
val xml = XML.loadFile("file.xml")
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you use something like `XStream` and map the xml to your case class and then modify as you want.

Comment: I just want to change very few fields (10) in a big XML with lot of fields (hundreds), so I would like to avoid to generate a (huge) case class. Maybe I miss something and I can use an existing XML with a simple case class.